# Angular implementation of Azure Communication Services Video Calling Features

Tags: azure-communication-services

We are trying to implement video calling features using Azure Communication Services using Angular but were not able to find any sample code to do the same.

Appreciate it if someone can share any sample code to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

See the following web quick start guide - [QuickStart: Add 1:1 video calling to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-with-video-calling?pivots=platform-web)

This is the package you'll need - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/communication-calling